# Getting form data to submit using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this form (As shown in the snippet). I have tried to console.log the form and it looks like this.

[image]

How can I get form data and send a POST request? I have tried `$(e.target).serializeArray()` but no use.

Can someone help me?

```js
$('#login-form').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(e.target));
    // I want to get form data and send a POST request here
});
```

```html
<form id="login-form">
    <p class="mt-5">Please login to your account</p>
    <div class="form-outline form-floating mb-4">
        <input type="username" id="username" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Username" />
        <label class="form-label" for="username">Username</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-outline form-floating mb-4">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Password" />
        <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center pt-1 mb-3 pb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary col-12 fa-lg gradient-bg-custom mb-3"
            type="submit">Log in</button>
        <a class="text-muted" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pb-4">
        <p class="mb-0 me-2">Don't have an account?</p>
        <button type="button" id="signup-button"
            class="btn btn-outline-danger">Create new</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: So you aren't looking to use the form's normal action to submit the form? If that is the case, checkout **$.ajax**

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to send an Ajax request. You can try this

```
$('#login-form').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post( 'YOUR_AJAX_URL', $('#login-form').serializeArray(), function(resp) {
       console.log('POST REQUEST WAS SENT');
    });        
});
```